# Get the conditions that returned true in Django filter

Tags: django, filter, conditional-statements, django-queryset

I am creating a queryset using a list of OR conditions.

```
objects = objects = mModel.objects.filter(Q(creator=owner) | Q(moderated=False))
```

Is there a "django" way to retrieve the OR conditions that returned true, after the execution of the query?

Thank you.

Comment: Surely it will be different for each row in the results, won't it?

Answer (score 3):

Use "Q" form django models.

Like this:

```
        from django.db.models import Q

        objects = mModel.objects.filter(Q(condition_1) | Q(condition_2))

        for item in objects:

           if item.creator == owner:
               print "condition_1 is true for object" + item

           if item.moderated==False:
               print "condition_2 is true for object" + item

           if (item.creator == owner and item.moderated==False):
               print "Both conditions are True"
```

Comment: ok, how can I get when Q(condition_1) was true or Q(condition_2) was true, or when both are true

Comment: @Theo By looking at the results.and then by using other operations on objects list.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "By looking at the results"?

Comment: @Theo Edited my answer,here field1 and field2 are fields of mModel table/model.

Comment: explicitly speaking, check if results equals to `None`. If its none, then your queryset contains no results. In case you want to know if any of the queries returned an empty queryset, then check each one separately.@PrakharTrivedi +1 for mentioning `Q`.

Comment: @cutteeth Exactly :)

Comment: The question of the op is, how will I know which condition gave me the results?

Comment: @Theo Please update your questions with exact conditions for condition1 and condition2,Then I can help you out.What are conditions 1 and 2 ??

Comment: @Theo Try this . But I think its more common sense than coding .